# Using poLCA.posterior in R

Tags: r, statistics

I am using `poLCA` to generate posterior latent class membership probabilities.  I need to assign each of 477 participants to one of three classes.  The process is a bit tedious, as I am having to look at each of three probabilities for every case.

Is there a way to have R generate a dummy variable for latent class membership based on the posterior estimations?  Said another way, is there a code that will generate latent class membership assignments based on the optimal probability of membership?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at `predclass`, the vector of predicted class memberships by modal assignment, as indicated on the `poLCA` help page.  For example, if you do

```
data(values)
two.class.model = poLCA(cbind(A,B,C,D)~1,values,nclass=2)
```

then `two.class.model$predclass` displays the assignment of each record to one of two classes.